# ExtJS 4.2 Grid Form Binding (updaterecord on form edit)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid that on selection binds the record to a form.

```
gridSelectionChange: function (model, records) {

        if (records[0]) {
            this.getFormdata().getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);
        }
    },
```

Everything works fine, but if I change any field value the grid is not updating the record and neither the datastore.

I have read that I have to call:

```
form.updateRecord();
```

But how can I call it on every lost of focus of my fields (textfield, combos, etc.)?

Is there a way to do the two way binding?

Answer (score 1):

You can see a working example under Ext JS 4 SDK examples/app/simple/simple.html 
It binds a grid to a form inside a window.

**This is the code that do the trick:**

```
    editUser: function(grid, record) {  // this function fires when dblClick on itemRow
        var edit = Ext.create('AM.view.user.Edit').show();   //creates a window a shows it

        edit.down('form').loadRecord(record);  //reference the form and load the record
    },

updateUser: function(button) {         //this function fires on save button of the form
    var win    = button.up('window'),  //get a reference to the window 
        form   = win.down('form'),     // get a reference to the form 
        record = form.getRecord(),     // get the form record
        values = form.getValues();     // get the values of the form

    record.set(values);                //set the values to the record (same object shared with the grid) 
    win.close();                      //close window
    this.getUsersStore().sync();      // this line is only necesary if you want to synchronize with the server
}
```

**Bottom line do:**

```
  var record = form.getRecord(),     
      values = form.getValues();     
      record.set(values);
```

Comment: That works for saving one record at a time. But I would like to update my grid from the form fields and at the end Sync all modified records to the server. Any clue?

Comment: just remove this.getUsersStore().sync(); to let the records remain dirty in the grid and on user click on update button (on a grid toolbar) then synch.

Comment: Is not possible to listen to the lost focus event for every field so after losing focus the records updates? Is that possible?

Comment: ?? I didn't understand this last part. So dblClick on a grid row, edit on form, save on form, record modified on grid but not saved on server, do this n times, then listen for a particular event and synch the grid store. Yes it is posible, just decide which event will trigger the synch.

Comment: Lost focus wouldn't be my choice because you don't know how many records are gonna be modified ... so either save after edition on form like in the sencha's example or find another event

Comment: So, what you recommend me is to edit all the values on the form, after that then press the "Update" button that will update the record and put on "Dirty" my store. And after I finish to update all my records that I need then press "Save" to save all in a batch. right?

Comment: I understood that's what you wanted.